# Problem with UTF8. italian/russian characters

Tags: errors, rss, encoding

I'm using an RSS feed importer. When i preview the feed, the special characters such as è,à and so on are throwing out gibberish.

Searching on the WP.org forum I came across the suggestion to add the code below to the wp-config file.

Adding the code hasn't made any difference at all. My DB is in utf-8 format.

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');           // force utf8
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');    // force collation
```

Any suggestions on this please? As I cannot add new tags (encoding/utf) putting this to the nearest available tag.

Defining 'gibberish'

è is displayed as �
ì is displayed as �¬
and so on

Comment: Define **gibberish**. Do you get **two** characters instead of one or **one** broken character?

Comment: I've updated the characters.. hope that this will help.

Comment: Does the RSS feed importer save feeds to your database? Or just output them on-the-fly on your website? You say when you preview the feed you get gibberish - are you talking about the feed you are scraping (i.e. the source), or the feed on your website?

Comment: It does save to the database. But at the first instance of any of the words with an accent the rest of the post is terminated. I am referring to previewing the feed before I do a full export.

Answer (score 1):

The content you get is not utf-8 encoded or the encoding is damaged by the importer. Usually SimplePie – the feed reader WordPress uses – is quite good at handling such cases. I wonder what an importer you use …

Anyway, I’ve written a function to [enforce utf-8 output](http://toscho.de/2009/utf-8-erzwingen/). You should implement this very early in the import process. The article is in German – let me know if I should add more explanations here.